# Getting the maximum size of a list from other class

Tags: java, for-loop, size

I am trying to get the maximum size of a list on the other class to set it as a maximum size in a loop to another class. As a result, it doesn't read the size that i get. here is the code:

Users.java

```
private void populateList() {
    CusInfoManipulator c = new CusInfoManipulator(this);
    int max = c.getMaxSize();
    for(int x = 0;x<max;x++){
        HashMap<String, String> value= new HashMap<String,String>();
        c.listData(x);
        value.put("username", "Username: " + c.getUserL());
        value.put("name","Customer Name: "+ c.getFnameL() +" "+ c.getLnameL());
        value.put("address", "Address: " + c.getAddressL());
        value.put("landmark", "Landmarks: " + c.getLandmrkL());
        value.put("num1", "Contact Number 1: " + c.getNumL());
        value.put("num2","Contact Number 2: " + c.getNum2L());
        list.add(value);
    }
}
```

the maximum size of the list from parse cloud:

```
List<ParseObject> searchItems = query.find();
int max = searchItems.size();

public int getMaxSize() {
    return max;
}
```

Can someone please help me to figure out what went wrong in my code and why it doesn't get the max size?

Comment: You lack a tag item, I bet [tag:java]

Comment: yes its java. i forgot to tag it. thanks.

Comment: `int max = searchItems.size();` then `return maxSize;` What's the difference between `max` and `maxSize`? How do you initialize `maxSize`?

Comment: Where are you setting maxSize?  do you have a setMaxSize method?

Comment: The full source of the class is needed to answer the question.

Comment: i re edit and recompile it also to my IDE.. it doesn't change anything..

Comment: `it doesn't get the max size?` What are the expected and actual results?

Comment: i want to get the number of rows i have in the table that i have created on the cloud(parse.com) in order to use the for loop to the other class which aims to print all the values in the cloud in a list view.. Whenever I do the code above, list view doesn't get the values.. but when i set a specific number on the for loop.. it retrieves the values.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but maybe you should do:

```
public int getMaxSize()
 {
    List<ParseObject> searchItems = query.find();
    int max = searchItems.size();
    return max;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

`getMaxSize` method should return something like `list.size()` instead of a constant value

Comment: Not necessarily, the list can just be added to, it would make sense for OP to have a seperate value of maxSize.  It would make sense to return the size if it was an array rather than a list.